# Salesforce JSON Nested Self-Related Objects?

Tags: json, rest, post, nested, salesforce

Looks like I need some help here. Salesforce documentation and multiple google searches not gave me an answer.

Problem description:
I'm trying to insert (POST) nested self-related records using REST with JSON, but every time this error appears:

```
{
"message": "Cannot deserialize instance of <unknown> from FIELD_NAME value records or request may be missing a required field",
"errorCode": "JSON_PARSER_ERROR"
}
```

JSON:

```
{
"records" :[{
     "attributes" : {"type" : "Test_Obj1__c", "referenceId" : "ref1"},
     "name" : "integr parent",
     "Test_Obj1__r" : {
          "records" : [{
                "attributes" : {"type" : "Test_Obj1__c", "referenceId" : "ref2"},
                "name" : "integr child"
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

Request:
https://mySandboxInstance.com/services/data/v37.0/composite/tree/Test_Obj1__c/
Authorization: OAuth security_token
Content-Type: application/json

So, as you can see Test_Obj1__c is self-related and Child Relationship Name is "Test_Obj1".

I've tested with different self-related objects - it gives same result.

If I'm changing Test_Obj1__r to relation with different child object - it works fine.

Is there any way to insert nested self-related objects through one REST request?

Comment: Did you find any further information about this unanswered topic?

Comment: Nope. I created same question on salesforce.stackexchange, but not helped much. Looks like it is a bug in Salesforce, because as I described there - Salesforce fails to deserealize structure which it serializes for Self-Related objects.
Link: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/163732/salesforce-rest-json-nested-self-related-objects

Comment: Okay, thanks buddy for your response.